# Re sizing and decorating text using css and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a side menu with 4 - 5 menu items. On page load event all sub menu are hide and when user click on main menu it's sub menu will only been show. I am able to achieve most of the stuff but the only confusing part is:

1. When I re size my page everything looks hazy. Like text is over written on menu box.
2. When mouse over any main menu it should show red under line.
3. When I click on any sub menu it's text color should be red.

[model][fiddle]

If possible, can any one guide me or show me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DFHWd/240/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1**: Try changing the size of `#master` to be absolute (in pixels) instead of a percentage for smaller screen sizes, using [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).

**2**: Can be done in CSS using borders, like this:

```
.expanded > a:hover { border-bottom: 1px solid #f00; }
```

**3**: Also done in CSS like this:

```
#master > li > ul a:active { color: #f00; }
```